# Does Black hole tears and compresses the nucleus of atoms?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, atomic-physics

**Part 1**

> Stephen Hawking describes the flight of a fictional astronaut who, passing within a black hole's event horizon, is "stretched like spaghetti" by the gravitational gradient (difference in strength) from head to toe.

**Is it possible for individual atom under go [Spaghettification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghettification) so much that at the atom gets torn apart,if it is near black hole?**

---

My logic is that the gravitational force due to black hole may overcome the strong Nuclear force if it is a large atom and tear way some chunk of it.

[image]

---

**Part 2**

In the front part of the atom,the strong force and the gravitational force are in the opposite direction while at the back part the both forces are almost in same  direction.

Since the force at the back part>force at the front part,

**Can this lead to the compression of nucleus?**

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/244974/spaghettification-on-an-atomic-scale