# Elementary particle (electron) and non-elementary (proton) spagettification

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, particle-physics, black-holes

I understand that spagettification means the vertical stretching and horizontal compression of objects into long thin shapes in a non-homogenous gravitational field, it is caused by tidal forces.

Now we talk about spagettification of objects, but the article does not say and none of these answers say whether gravity is strong enough near a black hole to cause spagettification of elementary or non-elementary particles.

[Spaghettification on an atomic scale?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/244974/spaghettification-on-an-atomic-scale)

[Does Black hole tears and compresses the nucleus of atoms?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/281363/does-black-hole-tears-and-compresses-the-nucleus-of-atoms?noredirect=1&lq=1)

There are two cases, elementary particles, and non-elementary particles:

1. I mean point particles with rest mass, like electrons.

As per QM, and classical view both, electrons are elementary, but still have rest mass, EM charge and magnetic dipole moment. In this case it is only a question of how strong gravity can be on the Planck scale, and whether an electron can be spagettified, and if we could measure it based on the distribution of its mass (if it gets spagettified) or the distribution of its charge or magnetic dipole moment.

If we could measure these things of an electron falling into a black hole, would the distribution of its mass, EM charge or magnetic dipole moment show spagettification?

2. And I mean non-elementary particles, like a proton, made up of quarks and gluons.

In case of a proton, would the proton falling into a black hole show spagettification? Would gravity be strong enough to tear quarks apart so much?

This case is not obvious, because quarks are confined, and the gluons can make a flux tube, and the force between quarks does not lose strength with distance, it stays constant, and when they are separated too much, new quarks are made with pair-creation.

Question:

1. In case of an electron (pointlike particle) falling into a black hole, could we measure the distribution of its mass, EM charge and magnetic dipole moment to get spagettified?
2. In case of a proton (made up of quarks and gluon) falling into a black hole, could the proton be spagettified? Could the quarks be separated by gravity, is gravity strong enough to tear the flux tube?

Comment: How could a point be spagettified ?  And for quark-gluon composite particles, we would need something we don't have to answer : a successful theory incorporating both quantum concepts and general relativistic concepts.   "Could we measure" requires we know where the observer is and the nature of the measurement process to answer this - quantum theory says measurement changes state (as it involves interaction).  So your question is essentially unanswerable, I think.

Comment: Elementary particles are *not* point-like. We are used to think of them as points and call them point particles, because the mathematical tools that we use describe them involve local lagrangians. But no real elementary particle can be confined in a region smaller than its compton wavelength.